# Vuex and axios, remote content not showing on initial page load

Tags: rest, vue.js, axios, vuex

been banging my head against this one for a day or so and need you to my rescue now.

I am building a rest-api driven vue.js site. I am using vuex-rest-api to get data form a copy of wordpress and then output it on the page.

The issue is my data doesn't display on load, throwing an error Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined",
. Once I start making changes to the code and webpack does a hot reload on save the content shows. It looks like the data is not available on page load. I can't work out with my current knowledge how to fix this.

I tried different lifecycle hooks ( such as beforeCreated()) for getPosts() but it didn't help.

Here is the code.

posts.js
    import Vapi from "vuex-rest-api"

```
const pages = new Vapi({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2",
  state: {
    pages: []
  }
})
.get({
  action: "getPosts",
  property: "pages",
  path: "/pages"
})
.getStore()


export default pages
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container header header--home">

    <h2 v-for="item in title" :key="item.id" v-html="item"></h2>
    <p v-for="item in content" :key="item.id" v-html="item"></p>

</div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  created() {
    this.getPosts()
  },
  computed: mapState({
    content: state => state.posts.pages[0].content,
    title: state => state.posts.pages[0].title,
  }),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      "getPosts",
    ])
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have miss type mapState with posts, but there is no posts property. L18-19 of your Home.vue file
There is a miss interpretation of type, between pages as `Array` and content/title as `String`. L4-5 of your Home.vue file

Home.vue

```
<template>
   <div class="container header header--home">
      <div v-for="item in pages" :key="item.id">
         <h2 v-html="item.title"></h2>
         <p v-html="item.content"></p>
      </div>

   </div>
</template>

<script>
   import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
   export default {
      created() {
         this.getPosts()
      },
      computed: {
        ...mapState({
          pages: state => state.pages
        })
      },
      methods: {
         ...mapActions([
            "getPosts",
         ])
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Great stuff what Ru suggested above.

Tweaked the code a bit:

```
computed: mapState({
    pages: state => state.posts.pages,
}),
```

Somehow the posts need to be mentioned with the vuex-rest-api I am using.

Also, to get the right data from the wordpress rest-api I had to adjust the loop a little bit:

```
<div class="col-sm" v-for="item in pages" :key="item.id">
    <h2 v-html="item.title.rendered"></h2>
    <p v-html="item.content.rendered"></p>
</div>
```

Thanks!